# How to Remove Layer and Route Line in Windows Phone 8 Map control. And Create Setting Task in map

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary

I have create route with waypoint--> ok 
But  then when I click the button current location (TRack Me ) ->  The application fails and exit.

this is source code TrackMe : 
[here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Map_with_directions_in_Windows_Phone_8)
and this is a source code Route Direction: (See More)
[here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Map_with_directions_in_Windows_Phone_8)
I think error by GeoCoordinate. Because after  click Button RouteDirection the object Geocoordinate in Track_Me is null.
But i can't fix error.

Sorry, Because EN very bad. 
Thanks you! please help me
And i need help :how to create setting task in Map control ( as ToggleSwitches GPS, MapMode ) custom applications
And Sharing Task ( share map to : SMS, Facebook , Gmail ... )

Comment: can you explain your problem a little more

Comment: Can you provide some source code of your project? (Both links point to the same website, there is no link for the TrackMe site). If you want to remove a specific layer from the map you can do so with `Map.Layers.Remove(<LayerName>)` and you can also remove all elements from a layer with `<LayerName>.Clear()` (you have to save a reference to the MapLayer you want to remove).